# Import DataRow in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datatable, datarow

i try to Import selected Rows into a DataTable to send it to a function. I go to Button Clickevent an set following Code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
foreach (var DataRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
  dt.ImportRow(DataRow);
```

But there is a error, cannot convert from object to DataRow. Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: The item returned from "dataGridView1.SelectedRows" shall be of type "GridViewItem" instead of DataRow.

Comment: Actualy it must be `DataGridViewRow` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedrowcollection.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `ImportRow` because it requires a `DataRow`. `DataGridView.SelectedRows` will return a collection of `DataGridViewRow`.

A `DataGridViewRow` is *not* a `DataRow`. However, you can use the [`DataBoundItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx) property of `DataGridViewRow` in order to get the actual `DataRow`:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dataRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    DataRow dataBoundItem = ((DataRowView)dataRow.DataBoundItem).Row;
    dt.ImportRow(dataBoundItem);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. The dataBoundItem contain each row now, but in dt.importRow there is no action. I debug the foreach-loop the dataBoundItem contain the DataRow but the dt is empty. I don't know why.

Comment: @kockiren - It will only work if the DataTable you are importing into matches the columns of the DataTable you're importing from.

Comment: Is there a simple way to create TableStructur or should i create the structur with foreach dataRow.column

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)                        
_BufferDataTable.Columns.Add(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name);

Answer (score 2):

[DataTable.ImportRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx) takes a [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx). Your datagridview1 however contains [DataGridViewRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx). You'll need to find a way to convert ([example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/6df9d2fc-c964-412f-819d-dd3596a7db51)) between the two, or construct new DataRow's from your DataGridViewRow's data.